# F#: Marten does not load the aggregate

Tags: c#, f#, marten

I am adapting an example of Marten in C# to F#, but curiously can't really get the right value of my aggregation:

```ml
open System
open Marten
open Marten.Schema.Identity

type AccountCreation = {
    Owner: string
    AccountId: Guid
    CreatedAt: DateTimeOffset
    StartingBalance: decimal
}

type Transaction = {
    To: Guid
    From: Guid
    Description: string
    Time: DateTimeOffset
    Amount: decimal
}

type AccountEvent =
    | AccountCreated of AccountCreation
    | AccountCredited of Transaction
    | AccountDebited of Transaction

type Account() =
    member val Id = Unchecked.defaultof<Guid> with get,set
    member val Owner = Unchecked.defaultof<string> with get,set
    member val Balance = Unchecked.defaultof<decimal> with get,set
    member val CreatedAt = Unchecked.defaultof<DateTimeOffset> with get,set
    member val UpdatedAt = Unchecked.defaultof<DateTimeOffset> with get,set

    member this.Apply(accountEvent: AccountEvent) =
        match accountEvent with
        | AccountEvent.AccountCreated accountCreation ->
            this.Id <- accountCreation.AccountId
            this.Owner <- accountCreation.Owner
            this.Balance <- accountCreation.StartingBalance
            this.CreatedAt <- accountCreation.CreatedAt
            this.UpdatedAt <- accountCreation.CreatedAt
        | _ -> ()

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    use store = DocumentStore.For(fun options ->
            let connectionString = sprintf "host=%s;database=%s;username=%s;password=%s"
                                       "localhost"
                                       "postgres"
                                       "root"
                                       "root"
            options.Connection(connectionString)
            options.Events.AddEventType(typeof<AccountEvent>)
            options.Events.InlineProjections.AggregateStreamsWith<Account>() |> ignore
        )

    use session = store.LightweightSession()

    let khalidId = CombGuidIdGeneration.NewGuid()

    let khalid = AccountEvent.AccountCreated({
        Owner = "Khalid Abuhakmeh"
        AccountId = khalidId
        StartingBalance = 1000m
        CreatedAt = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
    })

    session.Events.Append(khalidId, khalid) |> ignore

    session.SaveChangesAsync()
    |> Async.AwaitTask
    |> Async.RunSynchronously

    let account = session.LoadAsync<Account>(khalidId)
                    |> Async.AwaitTask
                    |> Async.RunSynchronously

    let stream = session.Events.FetchStream(khalidId)

    printfn "%A" account
    printfn "%A" stream

    0
```

The issue is that when requesting the document corresponding to the aggregation with the related id, it just returns `null`

```ml
let account = session.LoadAsync<Account>(khalidId)
                |> Async.AwaitTask
                |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Curiously fetching the stream of events return the event as expected:

```ml
let stream = session.Events.FetchStream(khalidId)
```

It's like the projection is never built or stored hence the `Account` aggregate `Apply` method is never called.

Source: [Marten - Projections](http://jasperfx.github.io/marten/documentation/events/projections/#aggregator-lookup)

---

[EDIT]

It turns out that if I am not using discriminated unions and directly the type of the different cases it works:

```ml
open System
open Marten
open Marten.Schema.Identity

type AccountCreation = {
    Owner: string
    AccountId: Guid
    CreatedAt: DateTimeOffset
    StartingBalance: decimal
}

type Transaction = {
    To: Guid
    From: Guid
    Description: string
    Time: DateTimeOffset
    Amount: decimal
}

type AccountEvent =
    | AccountCreated of AccountCreation
    | AccountCredited of Transaction
    | AccountDebited of Transaction

type Account() =
    member val Id = Unchecked.defaultof<Guid> with get,set
    member val Owner = Unchecked.defaultof<string> with get,set
    member val Balance = Unchecked.defaultof<decimal> with get,set
    member val CreatedAt = Unchecked.defaultof<DateTimeOffset> with get,set
    member val UpdatedAt = Unchecked.defaultof<DateTimeOffset> with get,set

    member this.Apply(accountCreation: AccountCreation) =
        this.Id <- accountCreation.AccountId
        this.Owner <- accountCreation.Owner
        this.Balance <- accountCreation.StartingBalance
        this.CreatedAt <- accountCreation.CreatedAt
        this.UpdatedAt <- accountCreation.CreatedAt

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    use store = DocumentStore.For(fun options ->
            let connectionString = sprintf "host=%s;database=%s;username=%s;password=%s"
                                       "localhost"
                                       "postgres"
                                       "root"
                                       "root"
            options.Connection(connectionString)
            options.Events.AddEventType(typeof<AccountCreation>)
            options.Events.AddEventType(typeof<Transaction>)
            options.Events.InlineProjections.AggregateStreamsWith<Account>() |> ignore
        )

    use session = store.LightweightSession()

    let khalidId = CombGuidIdGeneration.NewGuid()

    let khalid = {
        Owner = "Khalid Abuhakmeh"
        AccountId = khalidId
        StartingBalance = 1000m
        CreatedAt = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
    }

    session.Events.Append(khalidId, khalid) |> ignore

    session.SaveChangesAsync()
    |> Async.AwaitTask
    |> Async.RunSynchronously

    let account = session.LoadAsync<Account>(khalidId)
                    |> Async.AwaitTask
                    |> Async.RunSynchronously

    let stream = session.Events.FetchStream(khalidId)

    printfn "%A" account
    printfn "%A" stream

    0
```

---

[EDIT]
I opened an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/JasperFx/marten/issues/1283

Comment: I imagine that Marten, being designed by someone who knows C# better than F#, didn't take F#'s discriminated unions into account in its design.

Comment: @rmunn probably, curious tho, since record types seem to work, will investigate how everything is compiled.